# Detect SMS sent from intent, without SmsManager

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sms

My application enables users in buying parking tickets. My application constructs SMS with body and phone number, and it passes them into default messaging app. Because my application main functionality isn't sending and receiving messages, Play Store want allow me to publish my app with `SmsManager` and `SMS_SEND` permission.

I tried with `startActivityForResult`, but I receive `resultCode = 0`, no matter if user did send SMS or just pressed back button to close messaging app.
Is there a way to detect successfully sent SMS without `SmsManager` and `SMS_SEND` permission?

Answer (score 0):

> it passes them into default messaging app

It passes them to whatever the user chooses.

> Is there a way to detect successfully sent SMS without SmsManager and SMS_SEND permission?

No. What the user does with that message in the user's chosen app is up to the user.